# Any good command-line tools (for a build server) for validating websites?

Tags: testing, cruisecontrol.net, web

My team creates a number of dynamic/data-driven websites. We use a CruiseControl.NET to download the code, create test data, run unit tests, and install each site into IIS for manual testing. However we haven't found a good tool (or tools) that can actually run through some simple tests of the websites, such as checking for broken links or invalid HTML.

Are there any good tools that we can incorporate into our build process to automate basic website testing? E.g. check for broken links, check for HTML/JavaScript/CSS coding errors, and so on? Load testing would be great too.

Looking for something totally generic; we don't need to write/record scripts for playback. Just something to cover the basics.

Thank you!

-James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For link checking you could always look at http://linkchecker.sourceforge.net/ if that isn't suitable they list other alternatives.

It also seems like it is an active project.

JSLint does javascript validation and there are two options for executing it via the commandline so that might be worth a look too http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: Thanks, linkchecker is perfect! I'll also look into jslint.